# the loaded tensorflow model giving wrong and single prediction

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

This is my model and saved in in .h5 format.

```
def convolutional_model():
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation = 'relu', input_shape = (28,28,1)),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(128,activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(10,activation= 'softmax')

    ])

    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model

model = convolutional_model()

callbacks = myCallback()

history = model.fit(training_images, training_labels, epochs=6, validation_data = (test_images,test_labels), verbose=1)
```

and I saved the model with the following code:

```
!pip install h5py pyyaml
 model.save('mnist_model.h5')
```

I checked this model before downloading and gives pretty close results.

I used this model in a `fastapi` project with the code as follows:

```
app = FastAPI()

model_dir = 'mnist_model.h5'
ML_model = load_model(model_dir)

prediction_classes = np.array(['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'])

@app.get('/')
def base(db:Session = Depends(get_db)):
    return db.query(model.row).all()

@app.post('/prediction_url')
def image_prediction(image_url: str = '', db:Session = Depends(get_db) ):
    if image_url == '':
        return {'attention' : 'No link provided'}
    else:

        image_path = get_file('image.jpg',origin=image_url)
        img = image.load_img(image_path, color_mode = 'grayscale', target_size = (28,28))
        img_array = image.img_to_array(img)
        img_array = expand_dims(img_array,0)
        normalized_image_data = img_array / 255.0

        prediction = ML_model.predict(normalized_image_data)
        score = softmax(prediction[0])
        class_prediction = prediction_classes[np.argmax(score)
```

when I tested the same model it gives always the same output `'3'`. I know I am missing but couldn't figure it out.

I made sure the dependencies were the same in both cases.

Comment: aren't you using softmax twice ?

Comment: yes, but the error is not originating from there,